# Setting up Cognito Form to use a template to handle registration for multiple events

Tags: cognito-forms

I want to setup a single registration form template for multiple events.  Can you use the same form template for multiple events and show specific data for each event - as participants register?

- I want to be able to get specific data for the event so that I can show who signed up for which event as the form is submitted and allow for multiple event registration at the same time.
- some events are for pay and some are free - is there a way to make this a possibility on a reusable form?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways you can do this in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

- You can use [repeating sections](https://www.cognitoforms.com/features/repeating-sections) to allow users to sign up for one or more events where they can click "Add Event" to add an unlimited set of additional events.
- You can use [conditional logic](https://www.cognitoforms.com/features/conditional-logic) to conditionally show additional questions for a selected event.  This could work both in conjunction with repeating sections or you could simply present a list of events and show fields (or blocks of questions) based on which events they select.
- Regardless of your approach, if you [enable payment](https://www.cognitoforms.com/features/payment) via [Stripe](https://www.cognitoforms.com/features/stripe-payment) or [PayPal](https://www.cognitoforms.com/features/paypal-payment) for some of the events, the form will automatically collect payment only if the selected events result in a charge.  Also, especially with the repeating section route, the receipt would be itemized and grouped by each event and selected options, such as an additional t-shirt fee or other add-ons.

Here is an example of what this could look like:

[image]

You can try out this example using the following shared template link:
https://www.cognitoforms.com/templates/shared/CognitoSupport/ZooEventRegistration

Follow up via comments if you have specific questions regarding how to put your form together or contact us through support!